# Epub, pdf, azw3 managing in Python

Tags: python, pdf, epub

I am looking for a library to manage azw3, epub and mobi files in python, I would need to define several functions:

```py
def set_authors(path_of_file, authors:str)
def convert_epub_to_azw3(input_file, output_file)
def convert_azw3_to_epub(input_file, output_file)
```

I would like to be able to put epub and azw3 files in a suitable format to transport between several platforms, I would also like to be able to modify the authors who are often poorly fixed, all of this thanks to its functions.

Can you help me ?